# Laravel 4 Javascript Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4. I included a professional html template into laravel, and going to write a script for it but I've a problem which I am facing for the first time. I'm including `.js`, `.css` with assets but there is a JS code in the template, on `mainpage`.. And It is not working with laravel. Except that all functions are working fine, but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* initiate the plugin */
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID  : "itemContainer",
        perPage      : 3,
        startPage    : 1,
        startRange   : 1,
        links          : "blank"
    });
});     
</script>
```

PS: I checked, jquery library included into project.

Comment: Try this => <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
$(".holder").jPages({
containerID  : "itemContainer",
perPage      : 3,
startPage    : 1,
startRange   : 1,
links          : "blank"
});    
</script>

Comment: Do you get any errors or exceptions?

Comment: what gives `alert($('div.holder').length)`

Comment: @Pratik Joshi, <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready( $(".holder").jPages({ containerID : "itemContainer", perPage : 3, startPage : 1, startRange : 1, links : "blank" }); </script> is not working too.

Comment: @appnic there is no error or exception.. only code not working, showing all of the posts, not only 3..

Comment: @PaulRad I added alert($('div.holder').length) .. Nothing?!

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @appnic here you go : http://laravel.io/bin/XyNE

Comment: which pagination plugin you use? also give your HTML

Comment: @PratikJoshi It must be BXSlider. Here my HTML http://laravel.io/bin/XyNE

Comment: put your <script> code you have given above ,just before </body> tag

Comment: @PratikJoshi , I tried, it is still same..

Comment: Use jQuery instead of $

Comment: @PRatikJoshi still same...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that files (js) are pproperly loaded?

Try add "/" on start every link to assets (js, css...).

```
<link href="assets/css/my.css....
```

to

```
<link href="/assets/css/my.css...
```